# Equality in the field

Tags: field-theory

Are $3^{-1}$ and $18^{-1}$ equal in the field of 25 elements?

Could you please explain me what does the equality in the field mean? Is it somehow simillar to the equality in the ring modulo n?

Comment: It depends on what does 18 mean in this field.

Comment: The field of 25 elements has characteristic 5. It is usually constructed as a quotient of a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. So because of that, $3=18$ and $3^{-1}=18^{-1}$ follows trivially.

Comment: @Max Freiburghaus , thanks! So if we construct the field as you said, then it consists of 25 following elements: $0,1,...,4,x,x+1,...,x+4,...,4x,...,4x+4$ - am i write? And operations are perfomed modulo 5?

Comment: Almost. You're right about the set of elements. But operations are really  performed modulo the polynomial you took the quotient by. E.g. $x^2+x+1$.